# How to pass token in header as http get and http post?

Tags: android, json

I am trying to implement a simple JSON get and post to the URL that sends token as header. Can someone help me with passing the token in header as http get and http post?

```
if (api.method.equals("GET")) {

 try {
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(SERVER_URL + api.toString()+URL.replaceAll(" ","%20").trim());
                //httpget.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, Boolean.FALSE);
                httpget.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                httpget.setHeader("Authentication", "mytokenvalue");
                //List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content-type", "application/json"));
                //httpget.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                // httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                Log.d("111111111",SERVER_URL+api.toString()+URL.replaceAll(" ","%20").trim());
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                return readStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
            } catch (HttpHostConnectException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost request = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL
                     + api.toString()+URL.replaceAll(" ","%20").trim());
                request.setHeader(new BasicHeader("Content-Type","application/json"));
                request.setHeader(newBasicHeader("Authorization,"token=mytokenvalue"));

                response = client.execute(request);
```